# Force update of a ReferenceManyField from an custom action in admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have the following `Edit` component:

```
const UserEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit  {...props}>
    <TabbedForm>
      <FormTab label="Main">
        <TextInput source="var1" />
        <TextInput source="var2" />
        <TextInput source="var3" />
      </FormTab>


      <FormTab label="Images">
        <ImageUploadComponant />
        <ReferenceManyField label="Images" reference="images" target="user_id">
          <Datagrid>
            <ImageField source="url" />
            <DeleteButton />
          </Datagrid>
        </ReferenceManyField>
      </FormTab>

    </TabbedForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

The `ImageUploadComponant` is juste a componant that enable the user to upload a file, and it creates a new object on the API related to the `ReferenceManyField` :

```
class ImageUpload extends Component {
  onDrop = async files => {
    /* Uploading the file */
  };

  render() {
    return (
      /* A componant with an upload field */
    );
  }
}

ImageUpload.propTypes = {
  push: PropTypes.func,
  record: PropTypes.object,
  showNotification: PropTypes.func,
};

export default connect(null, {
  showNotification: showNotificationAction,
  push: pushAction,
})(ImageUpload);
```

After the `/* Uploading the file */` block, I would like to refresh the `ReferenceManyField` so the fresh uploaded image is shown.

I guess I have to put some kind of redux / sagas message, but I didn't manage to perform it. Any idea ?